# Finder spotlight tool not "grepping" through all file types?

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight

We've got this development stack that's mostly javascript, and if I'm looking for a variable definition or something I can use Finder's spotlight tool to easily find the file that contains the variable I'm looking for.  However if there's something I'm looking for that I know is in a JSON file, Finder won't return anything.  I looked through Finder's preferences as well as Spotlight's but couldn't find anything about extensions.  Does anyone know a fix for this?  Or maybe an alternative to Finder/Spotlight?  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use Bare Bones’s [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) (from the makers of BBEdit). It has a *Multi-File* Search function that is easy to use and pretty useful.

[image: TextWrangler screenshot]

Nice: TextWrangler is free.