# Why doesn't OS X Spotlight search inside .json files?

Tags: spotlight, search

I am trying to search a folder for an ID number. The folder contains various different file types. The ID can be found in several **.json** files, but non of them show up.

If I rename the **.json** file to **.json2** or **.jsont** then the files show up in the search:
[image]

If I try and use terminal and `mdfind` it is the same, **.json** files wouldn't show up when searching for the ID.

Is there some setting I need to change such that spotlight/`mdfind` will search inside **.json** files? Or will I have to rename all files?

Note: Some of the .json files are quite large (~16 MB). Does this matter?

Comment: possible duplicate (but without answer) of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86852/finder-spotlight-tool-not-grepping-through-all-file-types

Comment: This is very interesting. Even after adding "json" to the Richtext.mdimport Spotlight file and re-indexing it will still not show the file in the results when searching for text that is in the contents of a JSON file. It will show JSON files in the results if they are searched for by name though... odd...

Comment: See also this answer, suggesting a third party, but free, software solution: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/87231/185129

Answer (score 4):

You could try adding JSON to the Spotlight RichText importer.  The process for XHTML is described here, and should be analogous for JSON:

http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-archive/2013Jun/0079.html