# Is there a way to search through a folder of files for a word in the code text?

Tags: finder, search, json

I have a folder containing over 100 tiny json files, looking for a way to search through the actual code of these files for specific words and filter down to just the files that contain the search term.

Finder doesn't seem to do it, unless there's an attribute I'm not seeing. Perhaps there's another app for this?

I found this similar post but it has a link for how to add XHTML files but I don't know enough coding to understand how to adapt this to JSON files.

[Why doesn't OS X Spotlight search inside .json files?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118884/why-doesnt-os-x-spotlight-search-inside-json-files)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Has spotlight indexed the directory yet? Words from files should show up in finder search if spotlight has properly indexed the folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not scared of terminals ...

In finder, right-click the folder, go to services, select open Terminal here

Then:

```
grep -l searchterm *json
```

Comment: I'm not scared of Terminal, but what I need is something that will update in real time. So say I have an active search in Finder on a Dropbox folder as co-workers add files to the folder, the new matching items will show up in the results list. Does that make sense?

Comment: @RobertK  That makes sense.  Have you stumbled upon this [page](https://www.bustawin.com/configurations-to-empower-your-macos/) in your farings?  Seems to do what you're asking.

Comment: P.S.: I had no idea that spotlight also indexes cloud services.

Comment: will installing for Spotlight also add this functionality to Finder? The reason I ask is I need to keep working while this runs in the background and having a Finder window on the side of my screen makes sense since you can't have Spotlight open and work at the same time.

Comment: It would appear so ... I just worked the magic described above and searching for certain words in finder turns up matching json files.

Comment: I don't know enough about Macs though to say whether or not spotlight automatically re-indexes files when they're being modified. @RobertK

Comment: The issue I'm having is my Library/Spotlight folder is in my main Macintosh HD directory, and using cd .. or cd / isn't getting me there. How do I get out of my user directory to run the mdimport command? *NOTE: My user directory doesn't have a Library folder in it @tink

Comment: But it does @RobertK ... it's just that Jobs and kahoots think you shouldn't see it.  Quick fix: fire up a terminal, `cd  ~/Library` :)

Comment: oh duh, I was trying to use the Go To Folder dropdown in Finder, I forgot the old Command + Shift + . (period) trick thanks for your help! I'll circle back after I install to see if it works in Finder in real time. @tink

Comment: When I run the mdimport command does any text display to show any importing happened? when I enter it, it just creates a new command line. I complete the steps but when I search in Spotlight, no json files return for the keyword ... this is searching INSIDE the file correct? not for the file name @tink

Comment: Nope, no output shown.  But the re-indexing may take a while.  @RobertK

Comment: How do I know when it's done? I assume when it says Indexing enabled. and moved to a blank command line... or longer than that? @tink

Comment: It kicks off a background process. How long that takes I can't say, sorry. And I don't even know what it's called ... I'm a Linux guy and currently forced to use a Mac at work, using helping here as an opportunity to learn more about Macs  :). @RobertK

Comment: Looks like it's slowly starting to roll out. Thank you so much!! @tink

Comment: Glad I could be of assistance @RobertK

Answer (score 0):

Find Any File (FAF) by Thomas Tempelmann is the tool of choice for searching files by text content.

You can find it here: [FAF](https://apps.tempel.org/FindAnyFile/index.php)

Comment: This is wonderful! Would love something with real-time updating of results but I can work with this. Thanks @Gilby